# How Can I Cut This Sprite Sheet Properly?

Tags: python

So I have this sprite sheet and I was wondering if there is a way I can cut these sprites, I've been trying to cut the sprites with  [sprite-sheet-cutter](https://ezgif.com/sprite-cutter) but my sprites keep turning up in a weird way. If you got a method to cut these sprites sheets please help! thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used your link and it seems to work fine. I did a cut by columns and rows number:

[image]

This is the output (3 images out of 12)

[image]

Comment: thank you I didnt know how to cute the sprites thank you so mucH!